# J2me midlet that reads from HttpConnection throws IOException

Tags: java-me, gprs

I'm just starting to work with j2me. I'm trying to work with HttpConnection but everytime I run my sample midlet, I'm always getting an IOException which says that there is a connection error. When I test it with the emulator of the Nokia S40 5th edition FP1 lite sdk, I don't experience that problem. I'm using a Nokia 2330 phone with gprs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just configure a new access point for internet over gprs settings and activated it. Check this link for the steps: http://blogs.forum.nokia.com/blog/hartti-suomelas-forum-nokia-blog/2006/11/09/series-40-and-network-configuration